# make Ctrlp results only show filename?

Tags: vim, ctrlp

How to make vim Ctrlp plugin's results(file list) only show filename without path?

like:

```
a.c
b.c
c.c
```

instead of:

```
Desktop/Development/Project/XXX/src/a.c
AnotherPath1/Project/XXX/src/b.c
AnotherPath2/Project/XXX/src/c.c
```

Comment: "Press <c-d> to switch to filename only search instead of full path."  Won't this suffice, or do you really want to change the display?

Comment: @gregory or a way to customize the display，thx！

Comment: Ask the maintainers on their issue tracker.

Answer (score -1):

Add the following option to your .vimrc:

`let g:ctrlp_working_path_mode = 0`

For reference:
https://github.com/kien/ctrlp.vim/issues/96